# JavaScript: image slider changes only once upon clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, slideshow

I'm puzzled by the function of my JavaScript image slider since it changes the slide only once upon clicking next (I haven't worked on previous yet, but should be logical enough to re-adjust). The code is given by:

```
$(".room_mdts").click(function(event){
//get the target 
var target = event.currentTarget;
var room = $(target).data("room");
currentIndex = parseInt($(target).attr('data-room'));


//First way, by reuse target (only inside this function)
$('#room_details_holder').show();
//The second, by using selectors

//remove all "selected" classes to all which have both "room" and "selected" classes
$('.room_exp.selected').removeClass("selected");
//add "selected" class to the current room (the selector can also be the target variable)
$('.room_exp[data-room='+room+']').addClass("selected");
});



var currentIndex = 0;

var adjIndex = currentIndex - 1,
 items = $('.room_details .room_exp'),
 itemAmt = items.length;



 function cycleItems() {
 var item = $('.room_details .room_exp').eq(currentIndex);
 items.hide();
 item.css('display','inline-block');
}


$('.room_next').click(function() {
 adjIndex += 1;
 if (adjIndex > itemAmt - 1) {
  adjIndex = 0;
 }
 cycleItems(adjIndex);
 cycleItems(currentIndex);
 $('#room_name').text($('.room_exp:nth-child('+(adjIndex+2)+')').attr('title'));
 });

$('.room_previous').click(function() {
 currentIndex -= 1;
 if (currentIndex < 0) {
  currentIndex = itemAmt - 1;
 }
 cycleItems(currentIndex);
 $('#room_name').text($('.room_exp:nth-child('+(currentIndex+1)+')').attr('title'));
 });



$('#room_name').text($('[style*="inline-block"].room_exp').attr('title'));


});
```

The reason I had to introduce adjIndex is because without '-1' the slide changed by 2 on the first click, again, no idea why.

The Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/80em4drd/2/

Any ideas how to fix that it only changes once? (And also, the #room_name only shows after the click, does not show upon expanding).

Answer (score 1):

Try this I rearranged your code a little bit:
made your currentIndex global and assigned with the adjIndex. If that's ok I will improve my answer:

If you click on the right arrow it goes to the end and comes back to the beginning.

url: https://jsfiddle.net/eugensunic/80em4drd/3

code:

```
 function cycleItems() {
      currentIndex=adjIndex;
     var item = $('.room_details .room_exp').eq(currentIndex);
     items.hide();
     item.css('display','inline-block');
    }
```

Comment: Now, when I click on the "More Info" of a thumbnail - it opens the expanded slide, but upon clicking next - the index goes to 1, instead of the next slide

Comment: @Tony When you say next you mean the buton value ">>" because when you click on that it moves the pictures from 1 to 9

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry for being vague. Yes, if I press '>>' it would start from the first slide, even if slide, say 5, was opened originally. No matter which slide gets opened, a click on '>>' would start again from the first slide...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, great thanks to  [**eugen sunic**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3761330/eugen-sunic) for the little push that got me thinking!

I have finially cracked all of the pieces, although, I might have some extra unecessary bits of code, duplicates etc, but the functionallity is just perfect!

What I have edited:

1. I moved one of the closing brackets for the `cycleFunction ()` closing bracket to the end of `.click` functions, that is to make the variable global (at least for those 3 functions)
2. I changed the title writing function *from*: `$('#room_name').text($('[style*="inline-block"].room_exp').attr('title'));`

   *to*:`$('#room_name').text($('.room_exp:nth-child('+(adjIndex+2)+')').attr('title'));`
3. Added a few changes regarding `.addClass`/`.removeClass` to the `$('.room_details_close').click(function(){`.

Now, openning any of the thumbnails shows the title immediately (the right title), clicking '<<' or '>>' changes the slide to next and previous, respectively, while the title changes accordingly. Closing the expanded menu and clicking on a different thumbnail results in re-writing the currentIndex (hence, adjIndex too), so the function starts again with no problem. 
Please feel free to use!

The new fiddle is: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/80em4drd/4/)